# Error in phpmyadmin Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#551

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

**Error:**

> Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#551 count(): Parameter
>   must be an array or an object that implements Countable

**Backtrace:**

```
./libraries/display_export.lib.php#381: PMA_pluginGetOptions(
string 'Export',
array,
)
./libraries/display_export.lib.php#883: PMA_getHtmlForExportOptionsFormat(array)
./libraries/display_export.lib.php#1099: PMA_getHtmlForExportOptions(
string 'table',
string 'bpapluswpdb',
string 'wp_commentmeta',
string '',
integer 0,
array,
integer 0,
)
./tbl_export.php#143: PMA_getExportDisplay(
string 'table',
string 'bpapluswpdb',
string 'wp_commentmeta',
string '',
integer 0,
integer 0,
string '',
)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: To run the function: PMA_getHtmlForExportOptionsFormat, you need to send an array type of parameter.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just edit the plugin **_interface.lib.php**

```php
sudo gedit /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php
```

Find this line

```php
if ($options != null && count($options) > 0) {
```

Add (array) or replace with this

```php
if ($options != null && count((array)$options) > 0) {
```

Comment: Nice one, didn't have to reinstall/replace phpmyadmin

Comment: U just saved my day. To get exact line (551) i used: 

sudo nano +551 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php

Comment: This answer really helped me. How I fixed it is I used sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php , then pressed ctrl+W and searched for "if ($options != null" without quotes.

Comment: This worked for me, rather than installing new use this code.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Really smart fix to avoid resintalling or updating it, works for me!

Comment: I used this code instead, to avoid the cast to an array: `if ($options != null && is_array($options) && count($options) > 0) {`.

Comment: Its on line 551

Answer (score 10):

This problem also occurs when you have an older version of phpMyAdmin which may not play well with newer PHP versions.

TO solve the issue:

1) Download the latest version of phpMyAdmin from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/.

2) Unzip the downloaded folder.

3) Copy all it's content to /usr/share/phpmyadmin.

Be sure all matching files and folders are being replaced with new ones (those you downloaded).

4) Restart apache: sudo systemctl restart apache2

All will work.

Comment: Fantastic! just came across this after an Ubuntu SSD crash fix. Thanks' for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open launchpad bug for this with possible solution in the comments:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1768071